# Angular 9 NullInjectorError on Resolver Service in sub-sub-lazy loaded Module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, lazy-loading

I have an Angular 9 app. It has a lazy loaded module, which in turn has a child lazy loaded module.
The `SubSubModule` has its own `SubSubRoutingModule`. There is a `SubSubThingRouteResolver` that is only needed in `SubSubRoutingModule`, and it's this route guard that is having a heck of a time with `NullInjectorErrors`.

I am importing the resolver into the routing module, where I am also adding it to the "providers" array (see below).

My resolver is marked as `@Injectable()` (no providedIn), it implements `resolve`, and this routing module is imported into `SubSubModule`. The app builds without issue.

When I try to access my route I get the following error in the browser console (note that the module that is erroring is NOT the routing module, but it IS the lazy loaded module).
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SubSubModule)[SubSubThingResolver_Factory -> SubSubThingResolver_Factory -> SubSubThingResolver_Factory -> SubSubThingResolver_Factory -> SubSubThingResolver_Factory ]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for SubSubThingResolver_Factory!

The final weird thing is, VS Code keeps popping up a "quick fix light bulb" on my Resolver class, with a prompt to move the class to a new file. When I try that, it creates a new file (title-cased, instead of camel-cased), with all the dots removed (except .ts). I've tried it, and it doesn't fix the problem.

Everything works just fine without the resolver.

Is there some weird rule I'm not aware of, where resolvers can't be declared in lazy loaded modules?  Am I trying to import it wrong? This is my first project with lazy loaded modules and resolvers.

```js
import { SubSubThingRouteResolver } from "file";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        children: [
            {
                path: "whatever",
                component: WhateverComponent,
                resolve: SubSubThingRouteResolver
            }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    providers: [SubSubThingRouteResolver]
})
export class SubSubRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try register your `SubSubThingResolver` resolver on the root injector:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliran, I did try that (just to see if it would work), and it did not. But even so, I don't really want this service provided in the *root*, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should export the `RouterModule` that uses the resolver with `exports: [RouterModule]`:

```
import { SubSubThingRouteResolver } from "file";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        children: [
            {
                path: "whatever",
                component: WhateverComponent,
                resolve: SubSubThingRouteResolver
            }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [SubSubThingRouteResolver]
})
export class SubSubRoutingModule {}
```